Computability of composite function - special case
I was just thinking, but could not get to an answer: if I have two functions $f  : \Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$ and $g : \Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$, one of which is computable, say $g$. If I know that $f \circ g$ is also computable, does this mean that $f$ is computable?

Consider the situation where $g$ is constant.
